# How to fix laravel query Exception

Tags: php, laravel

other artisan commands working properly except migrate cmd. 
When I run "php artisan migrate" on terminal, I got

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = test and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known")
      /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=http://127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=test", "root", "", [])
      /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

In .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=http://127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I've checked php enable extensions by using php -m
    there mbstring, pdo_mysql, PDO extensions are already enable

Can someone help me what's wrong with this?

Comment: `DB_HOST=http://127.0.0.1` is not valid. Use just the IP or hostname, and drop the protocol.

Comment: I tested with db_host=localhost also

Comment: But did you get the same error or something different

Comment: Post the full error that you get with localhost or just `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I've already posted full error above

Comment: That's the full error with `http://`, which is invalid. What's the full error without it?

Comment: yeah the same err after changing DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

Comment: You are actually getting `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known` with `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `DB_HOST` value in your `.env` file from

```
DB_HOST=http://127.0.0.1
```

> to

```
 DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: If you look at the question they are not using localhost?? `DB_HOST=http://127.0.0.1`

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you> i have updated the same.

Comment: I just changed it and run php artisan migrate after php artisan config:cache cmd

Comment: nothing changed in exception prompt

Comment: @ZinMarHtun try clearing your cache by `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: yes just run and got same exception

Comment: Finally try to execute this `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: getting the same error